# How can i add a javascript file in html page?

Tags: javascript, html, function, popup, jsfiddle

Hello everyone and thank you for your time! I have a simple question for you.. I have an html page where is only a basemap (open street map). And i have also a javascript file, where it takes your coordinates and it counts a percentage. How can i embed this javascript file in the html page? I mean i want the html page to call this javascript file and after all, to appear a pop-up window where it appears this message:
"the percentage is..."

Note: This percentage (line) from the javascript file is that:

```
console.log("percentage:",(counter/(data.length/4))*100)
```

**Link to Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/irinikonsta/ho4281z1/5/

It's for my diploma thesis...Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just add a `<script>` tag with your javascript at the end of the page.

Comment: and how can i add this script file in the html page??

Comment: you open the html file and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add script tag inside your head tag in your HTML file.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following tag within your HTML head tag or at the bottom of the file.

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

You can read more about this on the site within the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: yes i tried this but it doesn't work maybe because there is the basemap...